# How to automatically choose minimal cmake version based on used features?

Tags: cmake

For example I want to specify [c++ standard](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 98)
```

But this is available only since cmake 3.1.3. Unfortunately I am still able to write at the first line of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
```

How can I be sure that I specify correct requirements (3.1.3 instead of 2.8)?

Answer (score 2):

The command `cmake_minimum_required` is not meant to check whether your code can be executed from the requested CMake version. The CMake policies are set depending on the requested CMake version, cf. [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html).
As a consequence, you have to test your code with the CMake in the version given in `cmake_minimum_required` and hope to catch all relevant code paths.

Comment: So, does it mean that the only way to do it automatically is to have installation of all cmake versions from 2.6 to 3.12 and go from the smallest available version upward waiting while there will be no errors?

Comment: You could do a bisection, but still yes. But this is not unique to CMake, it is similar to Python, Basic or JavaScript code.